# Jupyter Notebook with C programming Language (Windows OS)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-kernel

How do I create a C Notebook in Anaconda Jupyter?

When I ran the following commands. It does not seem to load the install_c_kernel python file.

1. `pip install jupyter-c-kernel`
2. `install_c_kernel`
3. `jupyter-notebook`

Comment: Hey wong try [this](https://github.com/user1095108/jupyter-gpp-kernel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I did to make it work was:

1. Enter Commands in Anaconda Powershell Command Prompt

```
pip install jupyter-c-kernel
```

2. replace codes in `kernel.py`:

```py
#subprocess.call(['gcc', filepath, '-std=c11', '-rdynamic', '-ldl', '-o', self.master_path])
subprocess.call(['gcc', filepath, '-std=c11', '-o', self.master_path])
...
#cflags = ['-std=c11', '-fPIC', '-shared', '-rdynamic'] + cflags
cflags = ['-std=c11', '-shared'] + cflags
...
#args = ['gcc', source_filename] + cflags + ['-o', binary_filename] + ldflags
args = ['gcc', source_filename] + cflags + ['-o', binary_filename]
```

3. copy `\jupyter_c_kernel` directory:

```
..\anaconda3\envs\py39-ijava\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_c_kernel
```

**to:**

```
..\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_c_kernel
```

4. run command `install_c_kernel`:

```py
..\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_c_kernel\install_c_kernel
```

5. Install gcc compiler:

   - [download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) mingw32 -> select `mingw32-base` and `mingw32-gcc-g++` -> `Installation` -> `Apply Changes`-> `Installation` -> `Quit`
6. Set Environment:

   - `start` -> `env` -> `Environment Variables` -> `Path` -> `Edit` -> Set new Path `C:\MinGW\bin`
7. check gcc version:

```bash
gcc --version
```

8. run

```bash
juypter notebook
```

Please `Vote` this answer if it helped you!